# JavaScript: removeEventListener not working inside factory functions

Tags: javascript

Here, playerOneSelects and playerTwoSelects are nodeLists with each three li elements.
For all li elements I have added eventListeners and it works. However I want those li elements to be not clickable after the start button is clicked, so I call removeEventListerners on those li elements. The removeEventListener function seems to be not working here. Can anyone help me understand why??

```js
const start = document.getElementById('start');

const playerOneSelects = document.querySelectorAll('.player > .one > li');
const playerTwoSelects = document.querySelectorAll('.player > .two > li');

const nameSelect = (item, playerSelects) => {
    function playerNameSelections() {
        item.classList.add('select');
        let array = [...playerSelects];
        let removeSelects = array.filter(name => name !== item);
        removeSelects.forEach(select => {
            select.classList.remove('select');
        });
    }
    
    const addItemListener = () => {
        item.addEventListener('click', playerNameSelections);
    }
    
    const removeItemListener = () => {
        item.removeEventListener('click', playerNameSelections);
    }

    return {
        addItemListener,
        removeItemListener,
    }
}

playerOneSelects.forEach(item => {
    nameSelect(item, playerOneSelects).addItemListener();
});

playerTwoSelects.forEach(item => {
    nameSelect(item, playerTwoSelects).addItemListener();
});

start.addEventListener('click', () => {
    playerOneSelects.forEach(item => {
        nameSelect(item, playerOneSelects).removeItemListener();
    })
    playerTwoSelects.forEach(item => {
        nameSelect(item, playerTwoSelects).removeItemListener();
    });
});
```

```css
.players{
    margin: 16px;
    width: 60vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 24px;
    gap: 30px;
}

ul{
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

li{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 12px 25px;
}

li.select{
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="players">
        <div class="player">
            <ul class="one">
                <li>A</li>
                <li>B</li>
                <li>C</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button id="start">Start</button>
        <div class="player">
            <ul class="two">
                <li>X</li>
                <li>Y</li>
                <li>Z</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre] that demonstrates the problem.. You can click on `<>` to create a *Stack Snippet* that runs run here in the page

Comment: This entire construct doesn't work. `nameSelect(item, playerTwoSelects) !== nameSelect(item, playerTwoSelects)` therefore the `playerNameSelections` function you're adding and the `playerNameSelections` function you try to remove are two different functions.

Comment: @charlietfl got it!!

Comment: thank you @Thomas. is there any other way that I can perform?

Comment: I found a way @Thomas. thank you again for providing insight.

Comment: As a side note, if you want an event listener to work only for once and then removed automatically do like `el.addEventListener("click", playerNameSelections,{once: true});`.